# Cloudera manager not running

Tags: docker, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to install Cloudera using below docker image on GCP :

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html

Once the process is completed i run below command:

```
sudo docker run --name=quickstart.cloudera --hostname=quickstart.cloudera -d --privileged=true -t -i -p 7180:7180 -p 50070:50070 -p 80:80 -p 8888:8888 cloudera/quickstart /usr/bin/docker-quickstart
```

But I am unable to access cloudera manager on port `7180`. I tried checking services running on port `7180`, but no service is running on this port. But I am able to access `8888(Hue)` and `50070(Hadoop Overview)` port.

Am I missing anything?

Running `jps` command gives below result:

```
275 DataNode
610 SecondaryNameNode
2781 HRegionServer
472 NameNode
3222 Bootstrap
1068 ResourceManager
1543 RESTServer
1774 ThriftServer
379 JournalNode
2168 RunJar
2616 Bootstrap
1957 RunJar
222 QuorumPeerMain
2656 HistoryServer
3660 
907 NodeManager
4552 Jps
1381 HMaster
752 Bootstrap
3577 Bootstrap
810 JobHistoryServer
3617
```

Comment: Note: If you really want to "install Cloudera", you wouldn't run all services in a single container

Comment: This is only for learning purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cloudera Manager is not started by default. To see options for
>   starting Cloudera Manager, run the following command:
>
> `/home/cloudera/cloudera-manager`

Reference : [Cloudera Docker Container](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-6-x/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html#docker_other_notes)